# Using AJAX to Change Form Input Options Based on Previous Selection

Tags: php, ajax, forms, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I have a form on my page which contains two select dropdowns. The first one lets the user choose a country, and the second one lets the user choose a city from that country. I would like for the second dropdown options to be filled with cities based on the previously selected country. Currently, I have an onChange event that leads to an AJAX script which populates the cities from an external php file. Here is my code so far:

**HTML Form**

```
<form method="post">
<select name="country" onchange="dynamic_Select('city.php', this.value)" />
<option value="#">-Select-</option>
<option value="India">India</option>
<option value="USA">USA</option>
</select>

<div id="txtResult">
<select name="cityList">
<option></option>
</select>
</div>
</form>
```

**AJAX Script in Header (dynamic_Select)**

```
<script>
function dynamic_Select(ajax_page, country) {
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: ajax_page,
data: "ch=" + country,
dataType: "text/html", //<--UPDATE: DELETING THIS LINE FIXES EVERYTHING
//<--UPDATE2: DON'T DELETE; REPLACE "test/html" with "html"
success: function(html){       $("#txtResult").html(html);     }
}); 
}
</script>
//I also have a link to the jquery file
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**External PHP File (city.php)**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// List of cities for India
if ($_GET['ch'] == 'India') {
?>
<select name="cityList">
<option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
<option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
<option value="Bangalore">Bangalore</option>
<option value="Patna">Patna</option>
</select>
<?php
}
// List of cities for USA
if ($_GET['ch'] == 'USA') {
?>
<select name="cityList">
<option value="Albama">Albama</option>
<option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
<option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
<option value="Florida">Florida</option>
</select>
<?php
}
?>
```

The above set of code isn't working, and I can't figure out why. Two dropdown lists appear on the page (the second one is initially blank), but after choosing a country from the first dropdown the second dropdown remains blank. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: So after playing around with it for a bit, I randomly decided to delete the line "dataType: "text/html",", and that fixed it. I still have no idea why though, so if anyone knows please tell me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your dataType parameter from "text/html" to "html".

Comment: I JUST realized that as you posted. I'm knew to AJAX, so I still have html syntax stuck in my head. Not sure what I was thinking. Anyway, that solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you were thinking in MIME ;)

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could have shortened all of this:

```
function dynamic_Select(ajax_page, country) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: ajax_page,
    data: "ch=" + country,
    dataType: "text/html", //<--UPDATE: DELETING THIS LINE FIXES EVERYTHING
//<--UPDATE2: DON'T DELETE; REPLACE "test/html" with "html"
    success: function(html){       $("#txtResult").html(html);     }
  }); 
}
```

To:

```
function dynamic_Select(ajax_page, country) {
  $.get(ajax_page, {ch: country}, function(h) {
    $('#txtResult').html(h);
  });
}
```